# Keep getting font family undefined with react native - links vector icons - build tells me to unlink

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I've installed galio framework, but I also have react native vector icons installed.

I'm doing react native by itself (not expo). And occassionally, more often I'm getting undefined font family, whether it be Feather or Font Awesome.

I've searched on the internet, and people say do `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` so I do that, fixes the problem temporarily, and then it happens again. I run the link again, and fixes again, then happens over and over.

Then when I close the simulator, and run `npx react-native run-ios`, build fails tells me that I need to **unlink** the react native vector icons...

Answer (score 0):

### POSSIBLE REASONS

If you are using react-native version 0.60++ then it must be the linking problem!

In react-native 0.60++ they introduced automatic linking so the command `react-native link library-name` won't work any more.

So it has to link the vector icons library automatically but for some reasons it fails to link it automatically.

### HOW I SOLVED IT?

Clean your gradlew   (`cd android && gradlew clean`) //Optional

Go to `android/app/build.gradle`

add this at the end of gradle file:-
`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`

Now re-compile (react-native run-android/ios). It must be working now.